# How to sscanf only the last word from a string?

Tags: c, string, scanf

I have a string ive read from a file using fgets and want to only scan the last word in that string.
For example if my string is

```
Hello my name is fred
```

I would only want to read the word 'fred'

I know i could just use `sscanf("%s %s %s %s %s", . . . . . .)` but that seems unnecessary as i only need the last value. Can this be done using sscanf?

Comment: can;t you use `strrchr()`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219940/traversing-c-string-get-the-last-word-of-a-string would do it.

Comment: @cad thanks for the link.

Comment: is there a way to do it using sscanf, i havent learnt strchr